# Store the Data in Local Storage

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this Component to create a recipe, but I want to store the data in the local storage.
When I print the "recipeData" it is printed on the console.
For example, I enter the name of the recipe and the description for it, etc. and I print the data in the console and the elements I have entered are printed, but when I print "recipeData.title" it is printed that it is not defined.
And when I want to store the recipeData in the local storage, it does not store it.
How can i solve the problem?

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
          <h2 class="btn-style">Create Recipe</h2>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <form @submit.prevent="onCreateRecipe">
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="title"
                  label="Title"
                  id="title"
                  v-model="title"
                  color="#43A047"
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="imageUrl"
                  label="ImageUrl"
                  id="imageUrl"
                  v-model="imageUrl"
                  color="#43A047"
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <img :src="imageUrl" height="300px" />
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="description"
                  label="Description"
                  id="description"
                  v-model="description"
                  color="#43A047"
                  multi-line
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="ingredients"
                  label="Ingredients"
                  id="ingredients"
                  v-model="ingredients"
                  color="#43A047"
                  multi-line
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-btn
                  class="green darken-1 color"
                  :disabled="!formIsValid"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Create Redcipe
                </v-btn>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </form>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      description: "",
      ingredients: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formIsValid() {
      return (
        this.title !== "" &&
        this.description !== "" &&
        this.imageUrl !== "" &&
        this.ingredients != ""
      );
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onCreateRecipe() {
      if (!this.formIsValid) {
        return;
      }
      const recipeData = {

        title: this.title,
        description: this.description,
        imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
        ingredients: this.ingredients,
      };
      console.log(recipeData)
      console.log("The Local Storage"+localStorage.setItem(this.recipeData));
  
    }
  }

  
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.btn-style {
  color: #43a047;
}

.color {
  color: #fafafa;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to store the data to `localStorage`, you have to define name of the storage first and then the data.

`localStorage.setItem('storageName', recipeData)`

to see the data of `localStorage`.

`console.log(localStorage.getItem('StorageName'))`

learn more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

and theres no need `this.recipeData` because u declare the variable on the function. to get the data enought with `recipeData`

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is a key-value data structure, you have to specify a key that will be used to retrieved the data from the storage as the first parameter. This is the syntax `localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);`

Also, it has to be saved and retrieved as a string, stringifying it when saving and parsing it when getting it.

Your code for saving the object should be like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('recipeDataKey', JSON.stringify(this.recipeData));
```

and for retrieving:

```
const recipeData = JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('recipeDataKey'));
```